# How to get user's affiliation in chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Is there a way to get user's affiliation in chaincode?
I couldn't found API for getting affiliation of user in chaincode.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on documentation of cid lib provided in [core/chaincode/lib](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid):

```
// Get the client ID object
id, err := cid.New(stub)
if err != nil {
   // Handle error
}
mspid, err := id.GetMSPID()
if err != nil {
   // Handle error
}
switch mspid {
   case "org1MSP":
      err = id.AssertAttributeValue("attr1", "true")
   case "org2MSP":
      err = id.AssertAttributeValue("attr2", "true")
   default:
      err = errors.New("Wrong MSP")
}
```

Comment: cid lib documentation does not provide API to get affiliation of user.

Comment: affiliation of user is to which organization does he belong, right? so all you basically need to extract is the MSPID which essentially binded to the affiliation. or is you need to extract a particular attribute from user certificate you can also find an example in docs.

Comment: Yes, attribute is a way. But i was wondering if i can get complete affiliation, like org1.department2.team1, not just MSPID

Comment: I think MSPID is different from affiliation. Affiliation is an attribute at CA level and allow you to define rules over user registering restriction. It is not necessary related with the MSP or to the organization an identity belongs. I'm also wondering if it's possible to retrieve the complete affiliation hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Affilation is coded inside certificate subject, in OU.
for example, subject for org1.department1 user

```
'subject': 'CN=33932069-6fce-4b16-8072-6715d591f35b,OU=client+OU=org1+OU=department1,O=Org1'
```

so, it can be easily accessed from chaincode

```
invoker, err := identity.FromStub(c.Stub())
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

fmt.Printf(invoker.Cert.Subject.OrganizationalUnit)
```